# Removing file path in PHP

Tags: php

In PHP, how would I isolate the filename and extension without anything else?

e.g.

```
/img/about/picture.jpg
/img/about/picture2.png
```

becomes

```
picture.jpg
picture2.png
```

I think it can be done using a combination of basename and/or realpath, but I'm not terribly sure how to string it together since I'm not exactly an expert in PHP.

Comment: This answer is far more inviting and useful imo.  But yes, that does look like a duplicate, sorry :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `pathinfo()`

```
<?php
   $path_parts = pathinfo('/img/about/picture2.png');
   echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
   echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
   echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
   echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
/img/about
picture2.png
png
picture2
```

Comment: So pathinfo makes my input an array variable, and then I can pick out picture2.png with $somevar = $path_parts['basename']; ?

Comment: Yup, you could even do `pathinfo('img/picture.png', PATHINFO_BASENAME)` to just get that item from it, with no array.

Comment: pathinfo($var,PATHINFO_BASENAME) is the same as basename()

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/basename

Basename returns just the file name and extension from an absolute or relative path. Also works for URLs.